# How to check if a select query result is NULL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, null

in SQL Server , how do I verify if a query has returned NULL and run blocks depending on it . e.g. in query 1 , I want to check `if count(*) is not null` and then check if it has >0 . Should I use `if exists` here ?

```
if select count(*) from tbl1 not is NULL then 
   if select count(*) from tbl1 where count(*)>0 then
      raiserror()
   end if 
end if
```

---

In Oracle one can say `IF INSERTING THEN` or `IF updating THEN` or `if deleting then` run a certain block of code based on a column  . how do we do it in SQL Server ? Please see Oracle code below .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_name
    BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF column1 ON tbl1
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.column1 IS NOT NULL)
begin
IF INSERTING THEN
    run some code like check if there are more than row in a table and if >0 then not allow any    inserts 
IF updating THEN
    run some code 
IF deleting THEN
    run some code 
end
```

Comment: `COUNT` never returns `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks , What is the use of  `-1` here ?

Comment: There is no use because `COUNT(*)` never returns `NULL`

Comment: I really can't think of a case for this, unless you use it in a subquery and join it. Then it's no longer COUNT(*), it's just part of a recordset.

Comment: Maybe my example isn't quite right . So my question was if a query returns NULL then how do I write a block depending on them . Maybe the count(*) example wasn't that good for this . But for any other cases should I use `ISNULL(select name from tbl1 where name ='a name')>0`

Comment: @ElectricLlama Thanks. Was looking for a way to formulate that :-)

Comment: You also say `where count(*) > 0` which doesn't make much sense either. Aggregates can't appear in `WHERE` clauses, just `HAVING`, and without a `GROUP BY` that still wouldn't work.

Comment: Are you certain you want to write a block? Or do you want to evaluate this on a row by row basis?

Comment: @user3844877 Maybe it would be better if you describe what you're actually trying to do. You'll get better results than with these contrived examples.

Comment: You might also want to review the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) on `ISNULL`, because I don't think it does what you think it does, given your `ISNULL(...) > 0` example in that comment.

Comment: Also keep in mind a query never returns NULL. A column does. A query can return no rows (in which case a COUNT would return 0)

Comment: If you are just checking if a query returns results or not then yes, you should use `IF EXISTS (<query>)...`

Comment: I have now edited the question and it now shows what I was trying to do .

Comment: So, you're writing a *trigger* and you want to detect what type of operation caused the trigger to fire?

Comment: Yes , that's correct Damien and then do the checking (I now have good examples for checking thanks to all the users here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @ErrorMsg nvarchar(400)
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl1) = 0
BEGIN
    SET     @ErrorMsg = 'You are returning nothing'
    SELECT  @ErrorMsg Err
    RETURN 
END
Else IF (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl1) >= 1
BEGIN
    SET     @ErrorMsg = 'You are returning something'
    SELECT  @ErrorMsg Err
    RETURN 
END
```

You can't get null from a count so if you do a check for 0 that's practically the equivalent.

The else if checks for anything that the count returns

you could also use an  `IF EXISTS`

```
IF EXISTS   (
        SELECT 1 FROM tbl1
)
BEGIN
    SET     @ErrorMsg = 'You are returning something'
    SELECT  @ErrorMsg Err
    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: You should generally use `EXISTS` rather than forcing the server to perform a complete count if all that you care about are `0` and `at least 1`.

Comment: Okay I added an If exist in also :p

Comment: Neither of those blocks of code are correct. The first one won't even run. You'll get a syntax error. Why accept it?

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM tbl1 = 0` is most definitely improper syntax. Why do you insist it works? With regards to the second piece of code: a count _always_ returns something so it _always_ 'exists'.

Comment: have you even tested it... sql-server it works perfectly fine, tested both so you are wrong learn the syntax yourself before you downvote my answers. reported

Comment: Yes the first piece of code works now that you have edited it. The second piece of code still does not function as you describe because `NOT EXISTS (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl1)` is always `FALSE`. You might want to edit that bit now.

Comment: `IF EXISTS (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl1)` _always_ returns true. :|. Never mind. This question is a train wreck and the OP is long gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a trigger you generally don't bother checking if anything exists in the pseduo table, you just write the code based off the pseudo table. Also note that oracle triggers perform row by row and SQL Server triggers are called once, with possibly mutliple records in psuedo tables.

So you'd do something like this in your trigger:

```
INSERT INTO AnotherTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT Col1,Col3 FROM INSERTED
```

`INSERTED` is a pseudo table. It contains all records inserted (or updated). There might be 0,1, or many records in here.

If there are zero records, nothing will be inserted by this code.

Back to your original question, the best way to check if there are no rows is to do this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED)
BEGIN
-- Some Code
END
```

Or, in a trigger, you can simply specify the trigger does not fire at all for UPDATE or INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

```
select FOUND_ROWS();
```

will return no. of records selected by select query.