# Which one is better: NOT EXIST [data] vs ISNULL([data], '') = 0

Tags: sql-server, performance, null

### The situation

In an attempt to find a row where a specific column has a `null` value, one of my colleagues verified if data in a column is `null` by making the data empty if `null`:

```
IF (SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ISNULL([column], '')) = ''
```

But from I understood from multiple example here on Stack Overflow ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31606314/3229805) and [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25324659/3229805)), this form is more common:

```
IF EXIST (SELECT [column] FROM [table])
```

By trying to make our code more performant and by trying to adopt similar coding behavior/standard we came across this interrogation.

I expect the second way to be more performant, because it does not call a function, but I am far from being an expert in [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).

### The question:

- Which one is more performant?
- Which one is better practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In an attempt to find a row where a specific column has a `null` value, one of my colleague verify if a data in a column is `null` by making the data empty if `null`:
>
> `...WHERE ISNULL([column], '') = ''`

Regardless of any other efficiencies that can be found, it seems a bit silly to use `ISNULL()` when instead this condition can very easily be expresseed as:

```
WHERE [column] IS NULL
```

Now, in cases when you are needing to test to see if "at least 1" row meets a particular condition, then yes, using `EXISTS` is nearly always (maybe even always) more efficient than not using `EXISTS` because the `EXISTS` operator is designed to exit upon finding the first row. When no rows are returned then maybe both methods are equivalent, but if at least one row is present, then the `EXISTS` is definitely better because it won't process any additional result rows since the answer has already been logically determined as `true`. The efficiency is more apparent when there are many rows that meet the filtering condition(s).

Hence, the most efficient means of doing this particular test would be:

```
IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [Column] IS NULL))
BEGIN
   ...
END;
```

So yes, try to always use `EXISTS` (whenever possible). And please read the MSDN page for the [EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) operator as it has additional info regarding using it in `WHERE` clauses.

For info on how to test for efficiency, please refer to the related question that you posted on DBA.StackExchange:

[Performance and profiling on SELECT * FROM [table] ISNULL([column], '') = '' VS EXIST (SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [condition])](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146825/performance-and-profiling-on-select-from-table-isnullcolumn-vs)

Comment: You provided as expected! Great answer

Answer (score 2):

- Which one is more performant? - measure it by profiling.
- Which one is better practice? - it depends.

`IF (SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ISNULL([column], '')) = ''` is treating missing data exactly the same as an empty string whereas `IF EXIST (SELECT [column] FROM [table])` is treating them as being different.

So it depends on whether `data` can legitimately be an empty string or not. If it can't then the former is OK, if it can the go with the latter.

Comment: How do you do a profiling to mesure performance? Just to be sure: which method is called depends on if the data should be null or not?

Comment: @Chax - I'm not an expert on profile SQL queries, so I won't go into that. Check on [dba.stackexchange] for tips. Yes, the "it depends" is on whether  `data` being null is the same as `data` being an empty string, and that's a question only you (or the customer) can answer.